# How to align divs properly without setting their position as absolute

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble in aligning divs in my project. I'm expecting something like this:

[image]

but what i've done so far is like this one:

[image]

All divs have class "inline"

CSS:

```
div.inline{
    float: left;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those 2 picture examples are the same, and what do you have against `absolute`? It's for this kind of thing...

Comment: That's the same image twice.. ;)

Comment: Is my old eyesight failing me or are both images exactly the same?

Comment: Start to add div 2 first then div 1 then div 3 and use float right :)

Comment: Already edited, I didn't notice sorry.

Comment: Are all `div`'s the same height?

Comment: @MathijsFlietstra they dont have the same heights.

Comment: @FDL our supervisor didn't require as to use absolute positioning.

Comment: so what are their heights?

Comment: Use a container, either a table with two trs and two tds in each tr or use a div container. Or use the display:inline-block; css attr.

Comment: If the don't have the same height you should probably surround each row with a div of its own and then float the divs inside. This way you will always have two divs floated on each row.

Comment: @IamDesai The height of the divs will vary on the data fetched in database. It should be dynamic.

Comment: @Natalie each row of divs will have their main divs?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Im pretty confused by this for some reason (maybe due to being early ;) ) So not like this? [Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/QwLZ4/)

Comment: Image cropping intensifies.

Comment: check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/LHxP6/ Here, instead of setting the widths and heights explicitly, you can have data filled in that will set the widths and height automatically.

Comment: @Ruddy thanks a lot. It worked. But there is an empty space above in my div 2.  :)

Comment: Forget my previous comment, it should be: Add this to your CSS `div.inline:nth-child(odd) { clear: left; }`

Comment: @MathijsFlietstra it's wrong. It completely align my divs vertically

Comment: No it's not. have a [look here](http://jsfiddle.net/mathijsflietstra/UWTQJ/).

Comment: @seed Oh good, my brain is awake! Shall I create a answer if that did indeed do the job?

Comment: @MathijsFlietstra it doesn't :( it's vertically align in output

Comment: Hmm I'm thinking maybe you have an older browser, then you are right, it won't work. But if you have [IE8+ or any other browser](http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child), it should work fine.

Comment: And you are adding the line to your existing CSS, and it doesn't work? Or doesn't it look good for you in the demo link I provided? Because it really is the proper way to do this, and it does work.

Comment: i did what exactly you've done.

Comment: Then you should probably provide more code as there must be something else which is breaking things for you, since the proper way to do this doesn't work for you.

Comment: @seed What do you mean there's an empty space above them? It works fine unless your other CSS is causing it to change and in that case its out of our hands unless you show all code affecting it.

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
    div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    margin: 4px;
   }
   div:nth-child(odd) {
    clear: left;
   }
```

See this fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/QkruA/**

Comment: @Era : looks fine to me...!!

Comment: Era isn't OP, anyway I posted this as answer in the comments a while ago, but it doesn't seem to work for OP, probably IE8.

Comment: it vertically align my divs

Comment: @MathijsFlietstra: ow. then fair enough. i didn't go thru all comments carefully. my bad. thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @seed but its working in fiddle. whats wrong with your layout.

Answer (score 1):

why not something like this?
just a little adjustment to deepus code: though the width of the parent and children must be set to your standards

```
<html>
    <head>
 </head>
      <style>
.inline
{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left;
    margin:2px;
}
.main
{
    width:120px;
}

</style>
    </head>
<body >
  <div class="main">
    <div class="inline">div 1</div>
    <div class="inline">div 2</div>
    <div class="inline">div 3</div>
    <div class="inline">div 4</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

go to old school way...`clear:both`

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZMGN4/)

**css**

```
div.inline{
    float: left;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.clr{
    clear:both;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="inline"></div>
<div class="inline"></div>
<div class="clr"></div> <!-- taa daa...i love old schools methods :) -->
<div class="inline"></div>
<div class="inline"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just use display:inline-block on each div

Answer (score 0):

To make it easy for you for in the future add a class "left" and "right" 
In this way you only have to make 2 very little css codes and you can use it every time you want something to set left or right (so you dont need to type this again every time you want to use it)

**CSS code**

```
.left
{
    float:left;
}
.right
{
    float:right;
}

.box
{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin:2px;
}
.main
{
    width:120px;
}
```

**HTML code**

```
<body >
  <div class="main">
    <div class="left box">div 1</div>
    <div class="right box">div 2</div>
    <div class="left box">div 3</div>
    <div class="right box">div 4</div>
</div>
</body>
```